# how to put url from database mysql to address bar browser in php

Tags: php, mysql, url

i have a problem in php..
i already stored video (arrow.S03E18.mp4) to my directory ex:C:/xampp/htdocs/telorbanget/media/ then i already write the path to mysql ex:http://localhost/telorbanget/media/arrow.S03E18.mp4
so, i have url in mysql now ex:http://localhost/telorbanget/media/arrow.S03E8.mp4
i want to put the url to my browser address bar so i can watch streaming this video through browser
can you guys help me to solve this problem?
thanks for answering..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing it in the browser, you can actually embed the video in the same html page wherever you are trying to show this video.
Other way to do it is to write a php redirect whenever user clicks on another page (`<a>` tag).

Comment: thanks for your respond.. can you show me a simple code for this problem? i can't understand.. thanks before..